# Blender 2.8 (and up) crashes on start

Tags: eevee-render-engine

When I try to open Blender 2.8 my **screen goes blank** and then turns on again with **Blender (Not responding)**. Other versions like 2.79 don't crash. I tried both 32-bit and 64-bit Blender

My PC specs: Windows 10 Pro (64-bit) ATI Radeon HD 4770, Intel Xeon W3565 16GB RAM,
[image: Blender Crash]

Answer (score 1):

[Blender 2.80 requires AMD graphics card with at least GCN first generation architecture](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/). The Radeon HD 4770 has the old Terascale 1 architecture and is therefore not supported.